# Computation of cohomology of Morava $K$-Theory

Tags: homotopy-theory, cohomology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $G$ be an elementary abelian group, so that $G = (\mathbb{Z}/p)^k$ for some $k$. We can then compute the Morava $K$-theory of $BG = (BZ/p)^k$ pretty easily: $K(n)^*(BG) = K(n)^*[[x]]/[p](x) (x)_{K(n)^*} ... (x)_{K(n)^*} K(n)^*[[x]]/[p](x)$, the tensor being taken $k$ times. We know that $[p](x) = x^{p^n}$. What is this cohomology $K(n)^*(BG)$ as a representation of $GL_k(\mathbb{F}$_p)$?
Maybe we can compute the topological cyclic homology via a slice spectral sequence computation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bjorn Schuster and I looked at this problem in our article `On the $GL(V)$-module structure of $K(n)^*(BV)$' Math Proc Cambridge Phil Soc vol 122 (1997) pp73--89.  In particular, we show that in at least some cases it is not a permutation module.  If you don't have access to the journal, there is a preprint that started off on Dave Benson's preprint server and was put on ArXiv in 2007: https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.0711.5016

Before our article, Nick Kuhn had shown that $K(n)^*(BV)$ always has the same Brauer character as a permutation module for $GL(V)$ in `Morava $K$-theories of some classifying spaces' Trans Amer Math Soc vol 304 (1987) 193--205, and this motivated our work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply and providing the arxiv link (I don't have access to any journals)!

Answer (score 4):

Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, you may find it more useful to consider $E^0(BV)$, where $E$ is Morava $E$-theory and $V\simeq(\mathbb{Z}/p)^d$. (Here everything is $2$-periodic and concentrated in even degrees, so it is sufficient to consider degree zero.) For each subgroup $W\leq V$ we can consider $E^0(BW)$ as a quotient of $E^0(BV)$.  For each character $\alpha\colon W\to S^1$ we have an Euler class $x_\alpha\in E^0(BW)$.  We can let $r_W(t)$ be the remainder when $[p](t)$ is divided by $\prod_\alpha(t-x_\alpha)$, and let $D_W$ be the quotient of $E^0(BW)$ by the ideal generated by the coefficients of $r_W(t)$.  This is called the classifying ring for level structures; it is a complete regular local noetherian ring and is a free module of finite rank over $E^0(\text{point})$ so it has very nice properties from the point of view of commutative algebra.  The natural map $E^0(BV)\to\prod_WD_W$ is injective and becomes an isomorphism after tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$.  There is also a natural filtration of $E^0(BV)$ whose associated graded is $\prod_WD_W$.  The action of $\text{Aut}(V)$ permutes the factors in this product in the obvious way.  This still leaves an action of $\text{Aut}(W)$ on $D_W$.  Although Galois theory does not always work well for group actions on rings that are not fields, in this particular case the behaviour is quite good.  A lot of this is covered in my paper *Finite subgroups of formal groups* ([published version](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(96)00113-2), [ungated version](https://strickland1.org/research/subgp.pdf)).  There are more delicate results in the same direction in my paper *Varieties and local cohomology for chromatic group cohomology rings* (with John Greenlees) ([published version](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-9383(98)00048-2), [ungated version](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.40.7848&rep=rep1&type=pdf)); I will not attempt to summarise them here.

As part of the same circle of ideas, the generalised character theory of Hopkins, Kuhn and Ravenel provides a ring $L$ (which is a free module over $\mathbb{Q}\otimes E^0(\text{point})$) and a natural isomorphism $L\otimes_{E^0(\text{point})}E^0(BV)\to\text{Map}(V^n,L)$.  This makes it easy to understand the action of $\text{Aut}(V)$ after tensoring with $L$, which might or might not be sufficient, depending on the details of your problem.